# Can I use two proxy servers serially?

Tags: networking, proxy

My organization has a proxy configured, and it is running well. There are few computer labs in this organization. Can i implement another proxy one particular lab to block web sites? But still all the network traffic should pass the main proxy server. Guys i'm new to networking

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a local "LAB" proxy, and configure that to use the "orgranisation" proxy as an upstream/parent proxy.